# how to use axios to capture http json response and pass value to another function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, httprequest, jsonresponse

I am trying to perform a `GET` call in typescript to various services and capture a value from their json response which will be passed in as a param in another function.

Through some online searching, I bumped into axios but am having a hard time wrapping my head around asynchronous apis and how to handle promises. Here is the code, that returns 'undefined' as an output.

```
function getVersion(url: string) {
let version;
let res = await axios.get(url)
  .then((response: { data: { buildInfo: { details: { version: any; }; }; }; }) => {
    version = response.data.buildInfo.details.version;
    return version;
  })
  .catch((error: any) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
return version;
```

}

I've also tried async/await but have trouble with unhandled promises. I don't need to use axios, any library will do as long as I can access the response to use in consequent functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can return a promise for `getVersion()`

```
async function getVersion(url: string) {
  let res = await axios.get(url)
  .then((response: { data: { buildInfo: { details: { version: any; }; }; }; }) => {
    let version = response.data.buildInfo.details.version;
    return new Promise((resolutionFunc) => { // return a promise
       resolutionFunc(version);
    });
  })
  .catch((error: any) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
  return res;
}

getVersion(url).then(res => {console.log(res)})  // use
```

or you can just return the axios, beacuse axios will return a promise

```
async function getVersion(url: string) {
  let res = await axios.get(url)
  return res;
}

getVersion(url).then(res => {console.log(res)})  // use
```

Comment: I want to retrieve the json `version` value from the response because I am storing this value. I am going to make this call repetitively since I will be polling for version values and checking against the stored values. Can axios do this? The examples I have seen involve console.log but I want to be able to capture and use the json data for other functions and to store.

Comment: @Carolyn Aquino I use console.log to check the correctness of the return value, you can do anything with the return value

Comment: I tried the latter approach in this manner:
 async function getVersion(url: string) {
  let res = await axios.get(url)
  return res;
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------
let myMap = new Map();
for (var i = 0; i < endpoints.length; i++) {
  let url = 'http://' + endpoints[i].endpoint +'/status'
getVersion(url).then(res => { myMap.set(endpoints[i].name, res.data.buildInfo.details.version); console.log(myMap);}) 
}. and I get a Unhandled Promise Warning